# Mi base de datos recibe los datos en el segundo click y no en el primero como debería

Tags: java, android

Lo que pasa es que cuando doy el primer click el dato en la Database me aparece como "0" y debería aparecer "1", sin embargo, cuando presiono por segunda vez el botón si me aparece el "1" en la base de datos... Ayuda por favor...

Este es el codigo de Android con Firebase

```
public class DatosUsuario extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button guardar;

    int size;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datosusuario);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        guardar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.guardar);

        guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference fbDb = database.getReference();

                if (fbDb == null) {
                    fbDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                }

                fbDb.child("num")
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                // get total available quest
                                size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();                                 


                                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("num");
                                DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDatabase.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                                String user_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                                currentUserDB.child("Número").setValue(size);

                              currentUserDB.child("Uid").setValue(user_id);


                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Te aparece `0` porque tú cuentas el número de hijos aquí: `size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();` no encuentra ninguna, o sea, `size=0` Y luego aquí lo que haces es agregar ese cero: `currentUserDB.child("Número").setValue(size);` Eso es lo que hace la lógica de tu programa. ¿No es eso lo que quieres? ¿Si quieres que empiece por uno, entonces puedes establecer `size=1` directamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo qué pasa es que quiero que cada vez que un usuario le de click aparezca un número más, por lo tanto, si pongo size = 1 siempre será 1 y no es lo que quiero. El problema es que si le doy click 2 veces al botón guardar este si me muestra el 1 por la cantidad de usuarios registrados en la Database, pero si le doy un solo click al botón guardar este me muestra 0 en la Database, es como si tuviese que dar dos click para que funcione correctamente el evento. Sin embargo el código funciona bien, solo quiero que funcione con un solo click

Comment: La variable queda en `0` la primera vez porque no encuentra hijos en esa parte donde estás buscando. Es lo único que te puedo decir, dado que no entiendo del todo la lógica de tu programa ni para qué sirve ese valor `size`, ni bajo qué criterios tendría que buscar, etc, etc. ¿Si le das click tres veces te sigue incrementando los números?

Comment: @A.Cedano Si le doy click no sigue aumentando, solo aumenta hasta la cantidad de hijos que tiene la base de datos. Por eso el primer dato registrado debería ser el Número 1, pero si tengo 3 usuarios entonces el Número sería 3. El código funciona bien, sólo que tengo que darle click dos veces al botón guardar para poder registrar el número en la base de datos, y lo que quiero es que se registre al primer click...

Comment: @A.Cedano el int size sólo muestra el tamaño o número de registros en la base de datos.